# Unexpected character error when using optional chaining

Tags: thingsdb

From the [ThingsDB documentation](https://docs.thingsdb.net/v1/overview/optional-chaining/) I understand that it should be possible to use optional chaining by using a "double dot" syntax.
However, even when trying the examples or the most simple syntax I can think of, I get an error complaining about an unexpected character `.`.

```
( nil )..x;
```

What am I doing wrong? Optional chaining doesn't seem to work as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you did not upgrade your ThingsDB nodes to the latest version.

Optional chaining syntax is relatively new and only introduced in version 1.4.6. *(The latest version at the time of writing is 1.4.13)*

I've tried your example in v1.4.13 and it works fine!

You can check your version using `node_info().load().version;` in a @node scope;

Comment: Ah, I postponed updating but shouldn't have as it is so easy!
Updating fixed my issue indeed.